# Changing the order of member definition corrupts memory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I've got a class with some member classes. Everything works just fine until I'm changing the order in which I'm defining the members.

This is the code which works:

```
  class Core{
public:

    /// Initialization and main loop.
    bool initCore(int argc, char *argv[], string dirPath);
    int mainLoop();

    /// Network impulse message
    static void networkImpulseCallback(unsigned char* data, int length);

private:
    bool                _running;
    string              _directoryPath;
    string              _serverIP;

    string              _loginName;
    string              _pass;
    string              _myShowName;

    /// System components.
    ConfigurationFile   _config;
    ResourceParser      _resourceParser;

    Graphics            _graphics;
    Input               _input; 
    ScriptInterpreter   _scriptInt;
    GUISystem           _guiSystem;
    EntityManager       _entityManager;

    /// Component threads.
    thread              *_netLoop;
    thread              *_graphLoop;
    thread              *_scriptLoop;
    thread              *_animationLoop;
    thread              *_physicsLoop;

    /*
     *  Initializes the rest of the system after the login.
     */
    bool _initPostLogin();
```

}

If I now put, for example, the `Graphics` object under the `Input` object, I will get a access violation. Where that violation happens, depends on which object I'm moving. I tried to figure out which object is causing the error by moving the objects around, but unfortunately got no result. The members of the object, in which the violation happens, are all uninitialized(for example a vector or a mutex). 
Now, my guess is that somewhere the memory gets corrupted. If so, what is the best way to locate the bug? If not, where could the problem be?

Comment: You probably overwrite data in some instance of the class, probably the `_input` member. Writing outside of, well, anything you have (structures, arrays, etc) will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which have the unfortunate property that it might seem to work some times but the next minute it will crash your program.

Comment: You don't have "member classes". You have *data members*.

Comment: What do your compiler warnings say (which you have set to highest level, of course)?

Comment: Have you defined any constructors?

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see where the AV is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some buffer inside Input class? I'd guess you write past the end and corrupt next member (Graphics).

Answer (score 0):

Did you allocate memory for your pointers to point at?

Is a library deallocating objects before you access them?